# RuboCop Naming/FileName cop complains about standard files when ExpectMatchingDefinition: true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I've searched for information about this on the Rubocop documentation but can't seem to understand what's going on.

Starting with a fresh Rails app (6.0.2.2) called "Foo", I add the following gems to my Gemfile and install them:

```rb
gem 'rubocop', '~> 0.80.0', require: false
gem 'rubocop-checkstyle_formatter', require: false
gem 'rubocop-rails_config', require: false
```

Currently the resolved version of RuboCop (given the version restriction I have) is `0.80.1`.

I then add a simple model: `rails g model user name:string`, which creates `app/models/user.rb`. Run RuboCop on that file only *without* any custom configuration file and it only complains about not having the frozen string literal. I do this under the context of my bundle with `bundle exec rubocop app/models/user.rb` and get the following:

```
Inspecting 1 file
C

Offenses:

app/models/user.rb:1:1: C: Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment: Missing frozen string literal comment.
class User < ApplicationRecord
^
```

Then add my custom `.rubocop.yml` file to the project with this rule enabled, which is different than the default value from the standard configuration:

```
Naming/FileName:
  ExpectMatchingDefinition: true
```

Upon re-running the analysis, this new offense shows up:

```
app/models/user.rb:1:1: C: Naming/FileName: user.rb should define a class or module called Foo::App::Models::User.
class User < ApplicationRecord
^
```

Notice how it wants the `User` class to be defined as `Foo::App::Models::User`. This happens to me on every file I evaluate. I've wiped out all my gems and even my Ruby and reinstalled, but the issue persists. The strange thing is that other colleagues can't reproduce the issue.

Has anybody seen this? I appreciate the help!

Comment: rubocop-rails_config is intended for the Rails framework code, not for Rails apps that you create.

Instead, you can use https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop-rails

(it's a little confusing because rubocop-rails_config used to be called rubocop-rails, but was renamed: https://github.com/toshimaru/rubocop-rails/issues/31)

Comment: Thank you for the response @AndyWaite . I tried what you suggested. Replaced `rubocop-rails_config` with `rubocop-rails` but the issue remains -- RuboCop still wants my class to be called `Foo::App::Models::User`.
This is what I have in my `Gemfile.lock` now:

rubocop (0.80.1)
rubocop-checkstyle_formatter (0.4.0)
rubocop-rails (2.5.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just recently merged a [pull request](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/7780) which adds a new configuration option, `CheckDefinitionPathHierarchy`, to this cop. When enabled, the cop will ignore the path and only check that your defined class or module matches the file name.

Once the next version of RuboCop is released, you can update you configuration file to:

```
Naming/FileName:
  ExpectMatchingDefinition: true
  CheckDefinitionPathHierarchy: false
```

and the offences relating to the namespace should go away.

Comment: Thanks @Drenmi, I've updated the gem and added the config and the offense disappears. Unfortunately this means that checking file paths is disabled throughout my app. I would have expected the old config not to want a pretty-standard model to be fully namespaced like `Foo::App::Models::User`, but I can at least avoid having RuboCop complain about every single file in my app.